# Ubuntu 18.04 cups printer get deactivated and print jobs hang

Tags: 18.04, printing, hp, cups-lpd

Every X time the network printer (using HP LaserJet 2055dn) get deactivated with cups. When you see the job list you see a list of jobs hanging. The printer status (computer is configured in German language, sorry):

```
root@ubuntu:/var/log/cups# lpstat -p Printer_Tray2
Drucker Printer_Tray2 ist deaktiviert seit Fr 31 Mai 2019 15:58:03 CEST
    unbekannter Grund
```

After you enable the printer again with the following command it will print all jobs again, but for some reason it get deactivated later again:

```
cupsenable -E Printer_Tray2
```

I thought that this had something todo with apparmor, but that one I have disabled to try:

```
root@ubuntu:/var/log/cups# sudo systemctl status apparmor
● apparmor.service - AppArmor initialization
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apparmor.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: man:apparmor(7)
           http://wiki.apparmor.net/
```

Also in the error logs or access logs there is nothing really special to see. The only thing you see in access logs is that print jobs get send successfully.

I have installed the printer the following way:

```
echo "Get the printer URL"
printer_url=`hp-makeuri -c 192.168.1.200 2>/dev/null`

echo "Install the printers (one printer per tray)"
lpadmin -p Printer_Tray2 -v ${printer_url} -P /usr/share/printer_drivers/HP_LaserJet_P2055x.ppd
lpadmin -p Printer_Tray3 -v ${printer_url} -P /usr/share/printer_drivers/HP_LaserJet_P2055x.ppd

echo "Enable the printers"
lpadmin -p Printer_Tray2 -E
lpadmin -p Printer_Tray3 -E
```

```
root@ubuntu:/var/spool/cups# dpkg -l | grep -i hplip
ii hplip 3.17.10+repack0-5 amd64 HP Linux Printing and Imaging System (HPLIP) 
ii hplip-data 3.17.10+repack0-5 all HP Linux Printing and Imaging - data files
```

Comment: Looks a bit strange. My 2035dn works normally with HPLIP. Do you have installed `hplip` and `hplip-gui` packages?

Comment: @N0rbert No clue, but I think it's standard installed right? I have updated the post and added how I installed the printers

Comment: The output of `dpkg -l | grep -i hplip` would be useful.

Comment: root@ubuntu:/var/spool/cups# dpkg -l | grep -i hplip
ii  hplip                                      3.17.10+repack0-5                            amd64        HP Linux Printing and Imaging System (HPLIP)
ii  hplip-data                                 3.17.10+repack0-5                            all          HP Linux Printing and Imaging - data files

Comment: @N0rbert Sorry for bad formats

Comment: All outputs look correct. But I have never added printers from terminal. Did you tried to remove the printer from `system-config-printer` and then add it again from `hp-setup`?

Comment: I will give that a try first when it go wrong the next time... Thanks